# whatsapp useless(?) files are safe to delete? dbcrypt and .trash

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internal-storage

whatsapp useless(?) files are safe to delete? dbcrypt and .trash.

I was never able to restore a dbcrypt file, and whatsapp creates many.

This folder just seems to try to fill remaining space with random data on my old J7 2015. (it is in the internal storage, unmovable)
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/.trash

It almost feel like they want to force us buy a new phone, because they fill it with useless files and then complain about no space left on device w/o showing the mess the very whatsapp did!

so, is it ok to delete them?
any other better suggestion?

Comment: You could try it making a backup and restoring from it will remove useless files. Then you're sure that they really are not necessary.